# How do I determine which item(s) are causing an event?

Tags: probability, correlation, causality

I have been keeping a daily log of foods and activities and also recording a symptom, say a headache.  I'm trying to determine if something I am eating or doing is contributing to the headache.  How can I do this?  I was going to put all my data into excel and try creating a correlation matrix but I'm not sure if that is the correct approach.  Also I don't know how to structure my columns.

In the end I don't want to make a prediction like in machine learning where you feed it a new set of foods/activities and it tells you if you will get a headache or not.  I just want to know the foods/activities that are causing the headache.

It's possible none of the foods/activities I kept track of cause it and I'm lacking some variable in my data like barometric pressure , temperature, stress level, etc, that I did not record.  I'd also like to know that too. (i.e. if nothing I recorded cause the symptom)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple approaches to such problems. One I found quite useful is using some kind of "clustering" algorithm like k-means, PCA/kPCA, t-SNE or UMAP and then exploring the data to see what factors may contribute to the incident occurrence in different groups. I often make clustering twice, once for all data (including no incident event, and incident occurred event) and then only for the subset in which the incident occurred. Sometimes comparison of those two allows to find similar "situations" (clusters) in which incident once occurred, and other time didn't. It may give a hint what particular factor causes the event (if such factor exists).

The other approach is constructing a classification or regression model (like XGBoost) which easily displays the information about the feature importance. It may answer the question which variable is the most important in occuring the headache. Then, again data exploration may be needed.

Also simple factor analysis using PCA loads may be useful, or in very simple cases ANOVA/MANOVA. Maybe correspondence analysis (with biplot) can help.

Also, it may be quite handy to use some BI software like [Tableau](https://public.tableau.com/en-us/s/) etc. to analyze the data toroughfully. Many of such apps allow to perform clustering. Then you need to prepare your data like for pivot tables in MS Excel.

PS.: I've read that most effect on headaches/migrenes has alcohol (obviously) and milk and its products (not that obvious), then chronic spine damages (bad posture, car acciddents etc). Also histamine (or other amines) intolerance, connected for example with insufficiency of diamine oxidase (DAO). Also exposition to mold may have strong influence to such symptoms. But that should be exposed by your phisician.

I've seen some apps in Google play which promise to analyze the data to connect factors to symptoms.